# Spring Boot Paging not working

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, pagination

I am writing **Spring Boot REST** server.

This is my TripController.java

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public GenericResponse<List<Trip>> getUserTrips(@RequestParam("owner") String owner) {
    Pageable pageRequest = createPageRequest();
    List<Trip> trips = tripRepository.findByOwner(owner , pageRequest);
    return new GenericResponse<List<Trip>>(200, "Success", trips);
}

private Pageable createPageRequest()
    return new PageRequest(0, 10);
}
```

When compiled, testing phase I got this error :

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project demo: There are test failures.

The full error report is here: https://pastebin.com/s4u5RX51

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the paging, the problem is it failed to connect to database while running your test suite.
Could you paste your pom file as well as your application.properties (under test folder)?